# How Can I execute a batch file i back ground using & ampersand in command line, but passing parameters?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I have the following batch file:

```
    cd C:\myfolder\MyScripts
    "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" runTest.js & %1
```

The %1 is a parameter that I send from a c# application.

The & is a command that allows to execute the process in background (this is mandatory for my purposes)

My problem is that the command line stops in the ampersand, and doesn't send the parameter to my file.
If I put  **"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" runTest.js %1 &**  with ampersand at the end, the process doesn't run in background and stops.

Can someone help me?

I need to let the process running in background AND send the parameter.

Note:  If I hardcode a value in the batch file It works fine, for example:

**"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" runTest.js & 500**

but when I use the syntax to pass a parameter value, it fails.
thank you so much!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" runTest.js & 500` works? Because in cmd.exe/batch file the ampersand is a special character, used to join two commands, it should be executing `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" runTest.js` followed next by the invalid command `500`. Perhaps you should escape the ampersand with a caret, `^&`, or double-quote the argument, `"& 500"`, or arguments `"&" "500"`

Comment: yes, It works.
Execute my process and pass the parameter. https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html
This trailing ampersand directs the shell to run the command in the background, that is, it is forked and run in a separate sub-shell, as a job, asynchronously. The shell will immediately return the return status of 0 for true and continue as normal, either processing further commands in a script or returning the cursor focus back to the user in a Linux terminal.

Comment: the '&' is not a part of the windows .cmd as far as I know or can find online. It's standard in unix shells to run a background job, but not in the Windows shell. That's done with `start /min cmd /c mycommand` - see https://serverfault.com/questions/121979/tools-to-run-a-background-process-command-line-in-windows/714560

Comment: Yes,  I know that but actually works. 
And I have not found something similar for windows cmd.  I tried  start /b and It doesn't work either.  Tried  START "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" %1  but  fails.

Comment: Your link is for `bash`, i.e. the Unix based Bourne Again SHell, not Windows `cmd.exe`, i.e. your tag [[tag:cmd]], which is used for your tag [[tag:batch-file]]. Are you sure you aren't confusing `bash` with `batch`? BTW, if you are referring to Windows cmd.exe and Windows batch files, please take a look at the information for the [[tag:shell]] tag, and explain why you have used it!

Comment: Well, the file has .bat extention, and It runs in cmd windows. 
So, that's why I deduced that is a batch file.
But, if It has commands from unix shell, what am  I doing wrong with the scripting? And why the script actually works in cmd windows?

Comment: https://htipe.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/multiple-commands-on-a-single-windows-command-line/   I found that & could be used in cmd windows.

Comment: 1. Open a Command Prompt window. 2. Type `cd c:\myfolder\MyScripts`, and press `[ENTER]`. 3. Type `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" runTest.js & 500`, and press `[ENTER]`. You will clearly see what happens. **_And BTW, that link tells you exactly what I already told you was happening, it is using the ampersand to separate two commands, and `500` is not a command!_**. Also you have not corrected your tags, as I've already mentioned to you.

Comment: 500 is not a command, is a value test that I hardcoded in the script to test if works to pass an argument.  and It works "passing an argument hardcoded" but not when I use the %1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those with the same problem as me, this is how i solved it:

I change cmd to powershell.

So the C# code finished like this:

```
 process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-File \"{ScriptNameOne}\" \"{param1}\"  \"{param2}\" \"{param3}\"";
 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 process.Start();
```

And I did the script in powershell like this:

```
param(
    [string] $param1, 
    [string] $param2,
    [string] $param3
)
Set-Location "C:\My folder\My other folder"
& "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "index.js" $param1 $param2 $param3
```

And works perfectly as I needed.